# Hide Class-View in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to hide the classes-inside-a-file in solution explorer?

It adds to the "noise" there. The drop-down triangles are quite confusing - I want to immediately see what files are hidden (in solution explorer).

Comment: @Mr.B The drop-down triangles are quite confusing - I want to immediately see what files are hidden (in solution explorer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use registry editor to set UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider value in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 to 0. Or save the following lines into a file called "patchsolutionexplorer.reg" or something like this and import it into the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0]
"UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Thanks. I hope there's something less "hacky". I rather not mess with the registry with undocumented settings.

Comment: You'd have to convince microsoft developers of two things.  1) clutter is not good.  2) the registry is not an appropriate location for user settings.  Until then, we live the microsoft way :)

Answer (score 21):

Instructions for Visual Studio 2017:

1. Close Visual Studio 2017
2. Open Registry Editor (regedit), select HKEY_USERS
3. File → Load Hive → `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_<id>\privateregistry.bin` where `<id>` is some hexadecimal gibberish. Set Key Name to the one you like e.g. `vs2017`
4. Go to `HKEY_USERS\vs2017\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_<id>`
5. Create new key `UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider` of `DWORD (32-bit)` type, value 0
6. Select `HKEY_USERS\vs2017`, File → Unload Hive

Comment: So that's what Microsoft understands under more portable settings, simply dump them into a registry hive file. Pathetic... thanks for this anyway!

Comment: I didn't have to load/dump the binary file.  I just added the dword `UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider` key to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_<id>`

Answer (score 16):

For VS2017 use `Disable Solution Explorer's Dynamic Nodes` extension [github](https://github.com/madskristensen/ToggleFeatures)

Answer (score 14):

or in VS Command prompt:

```
vsregedit set "%VSINSTALLDIR%/" HKCU "" UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider dword 0
```

Comment: This is the way to go!  Works on VS 2017, 2019, and presumably 2015, with no need to navigate regedit or even leave Visual Studio.

Comment: Still works for VS 2022. Restart VS afterwards.

Answer (score 12):

For VS2019 it's the same registry hack

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_<id>`

Add new DWORD `UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider` set to 0

Comment: I wonder how many more years will I have to keep searching for this registry hack.

Comment: Lol. 4 years later and I'm still Googling for this.

Answer (score 5):

info from this [link](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2013/11/04/hide-class-info-in-visual-studio-20122013-solution-explorer/)

> Still some people never use the Solution Explorer to navigate the code
>   symbols and methods. In this case expansion arrows on code files only
>   create distraction in the Solution Explorer window. There is no option
>   to control the availability of file expansion, but there is the
>   UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider dword registry value (discovered by
>   Julien Lebosquain) that you can set to 0 to disable class view in
>   Solution Explorer. The registry key for this value is
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0 for Visual
>   Studio 2012 and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
>   for Visual Studio 2013 correspondingly:

it's makes sense for you?

Comment: Thanks. But that post is almost 2 years old. I hope there's something less "hacky" by now. I rather not mess with the registry with undocumented settings.

Comment: If you want a UI for that, use VSCommands. Even while this feature is undocumented, it surely won't break anything in case MS decides to throw it out.

Comment: I added this key to VS 2015 (14.0) and the Key does not seem to work anymore :-(

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena that works for me just fine `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0]` and `"UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider"=dword:00000000` (32-bit dword)

Answer (score 4):

In VS2017 (and pretty sure in VS2015 also), click on the little triangle to the right of the search box in Solution Explorer. In the window that pops up, uncheck 'Search within file contents'. That will only show files in the filtered results.

[image: Solution Explorer Search options]

Comment: The question is not about the Search!

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for pointing that out. Will leave this here for now still as some have found it useful. Will try to move it if I find a related question.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late into the game.

This extension hides dynamic nodes.
[Disable Solution Explorer's Dynamic Nodes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.DisableSolutionExplorersDynamicNodes)

Answer (score 1):

If you install the extension VSCommands, you have a setting to disable this.
http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/

Go to Tools -> Options -> VSCommands 12 and press the "Open Configuration" button.

Now the configuration screen of VSCommands will open. Go to "Solution Explorer" under "IDE Enhancements". Now check the checkbox "Disable Graph provider" and restart Visual Studio.

Now the classes inside a file should not be visible anymore in the Solution Explorer.