# Showing all functions in a C File

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Is there some way to show which functions are inside a `C` file and jump to them?

I know that there is a class browser, but that doesn't help, because I have to work on some C99 code and when I look at the browsers I found so far, they show me structures or all functions from the whole project. What I would like to have is that I click on a source file and it shows me the types and functions which are declared/contained in that file only.

I'm using doxygen but that also doesn't seem to be able to show that, and I wonder if something like this is avialable directly inside the IDE as well. At least in Doxygen, I can't see which names are functions and which ones are variables or other stuff.

Comment: maybe visual assist x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For list of functions in the opened file, you can use the combobox at the top of your editor:
[image]

If you want to see them as in C# project referenced above, you'd need to upgrade to a later version of Visual Studio. 2013 has this feature for sure, most likely 2012 too.

Ironically, there is an ongoing discussion on how to HIDE this feature in modern versions:
[Hide Class-View in Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212661/hide-class-view-in-solution-explorer)
:)

Comment: Thx! Don't know how I missed that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio has this functionality built-in:
I managed to find a preety self explaining screenshot that might help you (It is a C# project, but the solution explorer is not different for C++ and standard C). At this time i run on 2013 so i am not able to double check it, but i remember it used to be just as it is right now.

[image]

Comment: Can't check with C# as I have only C and CPP projects, but this doesn't seem to be available in 2010 (or maybe only for C# files).