# Why does Visual Studio show extra file after generating new razor page?

Tags: visual-studio, razor-pages

Starting a new razor pages app with asp.net core and VS 2019.  The existing files from the new project template have the cshtml and cs files displayed and nested in VS solution explorer.

However, when I generate a new razor page by choosing:

```
Add new item > Razor page > Add ...
```

[image]

[image]

I then end up with what appears to be an extra "artifact" of some sort. 
What can I check?
[image]

**[ Edit ]**
Another view, showing razor pages that were added with a new project, vs those that I added
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's called Class View. It's been added to Solution Explorer to save you having to switch between multiple tool windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/viewing-the-structure-of-code?view=vs-2019

If you expand the `_Pages_Test` item that you highlight, you should see the properties and methods in your PageModel. Click on any one of them and it takes you directly to that point in code.

Comment: Ok, then why dont the other pages have this that were added as part of a new project?  See edit above

Comment: How can I hide that and only show the cshtml and class file?

Comment: I think I found my answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212661/hide-class-view-in-solution-explorer   Found this extension to disable this noise https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.DisableSolutionExplorersDynamicNodes