# Why do certain namespaces are shown as empty in Class View?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a basic Console application in Visual Studio 2019. I tried to check Project References in Class View just to see all the different namespaces and entities (classes,interfaces,enums etc) under them. I have not added any explicit dependencies so whatever is there is what comes by default when we create a new C# Console application. But I was surprised to see that there are certain namespaces without anything under them. As you can see in the screenshot below , I have highlighted two such namespaces, from the 'expand' icon you can tell that I have already collapsed them:-

[image]

Why is that the case ? What is the use of the namespace without any entities in it? And also I found certain assemblies (e.g. Microsoft.VisualBasic) without any namespaces under it , why?

Comment: You have to use View\ObjectBrowser to browse all referenced assemblies. There `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` is not empty. On your screenshot seems to be a solution explorer with class viewer (which I personally immediately [turn off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32212661/1997232) to reduce clutter), it's probably doesn't have all the functionality of object browser.

Comment: yes, but it appears that the Object Browser view is flat -- it just lists all the assemblies used across entire solution , it doesn't show hierarchical view , for example say I want to only see assemblies for a given project within a specific project. Object browser just lists all the unique assemblies across entire solution so we can't know which assemblies are used in which project.

Comment: Also , just saw that the issue very much exists in object browser too , those namespaces appearing empty , so I don't think it matters if we use object browser or class view , the issue remains

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be empty. Something is wrong.