# Blue padlock in Visual studio preventing me from accessing file structure

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

If I'm working on a solution in Visual Studio which has source control enabled, many (in fact all) of my files get a blue padlock symbol next to them:

[image]

For projects with no source control there's a small arrow next to my files, and I'm able to access their content and structure:

[image]

I conclude therefore that enabling source control in my VS2019 project tampers with my ability to access this small navigator, which I don't like.

How do I keep the source control but also keep the ability to navigate the objects in the file as shown above?

Comment: The icon is not a problem. It simply means that the item is under source control. The issue - at least a symptom of the issue - is that the names of the project items does not appear to be displayed next to those icons. That is not normal and means that something is broken on your system. I would be tempted to repair VS.

Comment: Hoover of the symbol and have a closer look what it says and tell us. If its just something like "checked in" @jmcilhinney is correct.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I just hid the names using Microsoft Paint for privacy. The names are perfectly visible in my system.

Comment: @Ralf please read my above comment, but indeed it does say "Checked In" when I hover over the symbol\

Comment: That icon is simply the statis. If you edit one of those files then the icon will change to a red check mark and then when you commit that edit it will change back again. That arrow next to a node simply means that there are child nodes below it. No arrow means no child nodes. If there should be child nodes and there aren't then something is broken but I'm looking at one of my projects now and I have the same icon on all the items under source control that have no been modified and those that have child nodes have an arrow to expand/collapse the node.

Comment: Then what is the problem? Padlock does not mean something is locked. It had different meanings in the past where it could also mean something was exclusively checked out by someone else and you are not allowed to edit. But those times are over. At least i hope no one uses such a system still. Thats why the text while hovering is more telling then the icon itself.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm quite positive that the .cs files with the blue padlock have at least one class definition with multiple methods. Perhaps the fact that I have source control enabled is completely unrelated and in that case I should possibly rephrase the question as follows: *Why does one solution have a drop down arrow for .cs files while another solution does not? What settings control the availability of such arrows?*

Comment: @Ralf The problem is that I want drop down arrows to check the structure of my file (classes, methods, variables) regardless of whether there is a padlock, checkmark, or what-have-you. Please see my comment above.

Comment: I thought you had cut them of the screenshot. The arrow would be left of the padlock. So outside of the screenshot. You see the space between arrow and text in the second screenshot? That's the space where those icons are shown. Then we are back to a broken Visual Studio. Maybe just broken dark mode? Can you click left of the padlock to get the behavior of the arrow? Just without seeing the arrow?

Comment: @Ralf I see what you mean. No, I didn't cut them off of the screenshot. They weren't there in the first place. Pretty sure there's nothing wrong with my VS install and I suspect there's a setting somewhere I'm overlooking.

Comment: What about the project that those items are under? Is the arrow displayed on that node?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yup. Projects, folders and XAML files all have that arrow. Everything except for CS files.

Comment: Seems it's possible to do this intentionally with a [registry hack] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55266273/9796331), interestingly. Perhaps check the value referenced in that answer? Additionally, if you haven't already, try Cleaning the solution, then closing VS and deleting the .vs, bin, and obj files, then re-opening and rebuilding. That should refresh Intellisense, which I assume is the component at fault here